# Remove background (from edges) from image and plot histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

Using python, I want to remove background of an image and plot histogram (bar) of the remaining part of the image.  In particular, I want to remove a black background into which the image has been embedded. This black background is in the top right, top left, bottom right and bottom left of the image. Following is my image:

[image]

The useful part of the image is the circular thing in the center, and I want to draw a histogram for this useful part of the image. How can I remove the said background and plot the histogram?

Following is my code of what I have done so far.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import bar
import numpy as np

im_gray = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')
im_arr = np.array( im_gray )
im_flat = im_arr.ravel()

mark_bkg = np.where( im_flat != im_arr[0,0]  )[0]
im_no_bkg = im_flat[ mark_bkg ]

hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(im_no_bkg, bins=30, density=False)

plt.figure(1)
bar( x=bin_edges[:-1], height=hist, width=1.0, bottom=None, align='center', data=None )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you store the image as `grayscale` [0-255].

To hide the `black` 255 background, apply a [`mask()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_equal.html) on the image.

```
# Removing black background
img = np.array([...])
img = np.ma.masked_equal(img, 255)

# Plotting histogram
plt.hist(img.ravel(), bins=256, range=(0.0, 1.0), fc='k', ec='k')
plt.show()
```

[Plotting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opencv-python-program-analyze-image-using-histogram/)